# How can I get a value of a countercolumn out of cassandra with hector?

Tags: cassandra, hector

Hello I'm trying to obtain data from cassandra using hector.
There are two ways of doing this.

one is with a cqlQuery like this:

```
CqlQuery<String, String, Long> cqlQuery = new CqlQuery<String, String, Long>(connect.tutorialKeyspace, stringSerializer, stringSerializer, longSerializer);
    cqlQuery.setQuery("select home from page_view_counts where KEY ="localhost");

    QueryResult<CqlRows<String, String, Long>> result;
    try
    {
        result = cqlQuery.execute();
    }
    catch(HectorException e){
        result = null;
        message = e.getMessage();
    }
```

And without queries it should be something like this, but I can't get it to work:

```
SliceQuery<String, String, Long> query = HFactory.createSliceQuery(connect.tutorialKeyspace, stringSerializer,stringSerializer,longSerializer); 
    QueryResult<ColumnSlice<String, Long>> result2 = query.setColumnFamily("page_view_counts").setKey("localhost").setColumnNames("home").execute();
```

Where do I make the mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your examples are incomplete, you give no indication of what is failing. But from looking at your code, there are a few things wrong: incorrect types, arguments, you need to use specific Counter types, and if just getting a single column then don't need Slice. This example should work:

```
CounterQuery<String, String> query = HFactory.createCounterColumnQuery(keyspace, stringSerializer,stringSerializer);
query.setColumnFamily("page_view_counts").setKey("localhost").setName("home");
HCounterColumn<String> counter = query.execute().get();
System.out.println("Count:" + counter.getValue());
```

If you do need a Slice, then the result returned from HFactory.createSliceCounterSliceQuery() will be

```
QueryResult<CounterSlice<String>>
```

which will contain the List of

```
HCounterColumn<String>
```

Comment: My first example executes well. The second causes a error with null pointer. But now it works. I find i difficult to find examples or good documentation on hector. Do you know a good site?
At least thank you.

Comment: http://hector-client.org, see the Documentation tab. Javadocs (API tab) are lite, but if you start with the HFactory class, you can browse through the convenience methods to get hints.

Answer (score 4):

Using the ColumnFamilyTemplate API might be the best way to get started easily. See: http://rantav.github.com/hector/build/html/content/getting_started.html (part or hector-client.org mentioned above).

Comment: Okay, I've tried it, but could not find a way to update/read counter columns. I also don't understand the difference between the 'ColumnFamilyTemplate' with the 'ColumnFamilyUpdater' and the ordinary "Mutator" or "Slice/Range/Counter/Query"(etc.) Are both methods equally fast?